# Autokey minimizing fullscreen apps when script runs

Tags: autokey

I am trying to make a script to take the non functional ingame side buttons of my mouse and  redirect them to keyboard keys. I successfully did that however there is a problem, every time I press the hotkey running the script my game minimizes. is there any way to stop this? thx

Comment: Ask this over on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/autokey/autokey). One of our regular contributors is a serious gamer and he will probably know how to help you. I think I've seen something similar to this discussed recently, but I'm not a gamer so I didn't pay close attention.